# String division

Tags: java, string

I want to print the string " my name is xxx"  as "xxx is name my" with out using Special methods (like util package methods in java);
thanks

Comment: You want to use the Java API without using the Java API? This is homework, right?

Comment: "String division" sounds weird.

Comment: For what it's worth, OP, this task is called string tokenization.

Comment: It's okay to ask homework questions, but only if you tag them as such and show some effort (as in, don't just expect someone to give you the answer)

Comment: downvoted. it's a homework, indeed.

Answer (score 5):

```
  String text = "my name is xxx";
  String reversed = "";
  for (String word : text.split(" ")) {
     reversed = word + " " + reversed;
  }
  reversed = reversed.trim();
```

---

If absolutely no method call is allowed, then it's a bit messier.

```
  String text = "my name is xxx";
  char[] letters = text.toCharArray();
  char[] srettel = new char[letters.length];
  for (int last = letters.length, i = last - 1, j = 0; i >= -1; i--) {
     if (i == -1 || letters[i] == ' ') {
        for (int k = i + 1; k < last; ) {
           srettel[j++] = letters[k++];
        }
        if (i != -1) srettel[j++] = ' ';
        last = i;
     }
  }
  String reversed = new String(srettel);
```

This requires a bit more explanation. We read the input array right to left (`i--`), and whenever we find a space, or when we eventually hit the left wall (`i == -1`), we copy (`for k`) the word we found to the output array (`[j++] =`). We keep track of the word boundaries in `last`.

Comment: Is split() is not a JAVA API?

Comment: @Helper: my philosophy is not to be judgemental and/or presumptious; I'm just here to offer the best, most instructive explanation that I can give.

Comment: @Helper: I finally read the community-written guideline regarding homework (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow), which I probably should've done earlier. In any case, "Don't downvote others who answer homework questions in good faith, even if they break these guidelines.". As for my part, I'll provide pseudocodes instead next time.

Comment: I'm sorry then, didn't know these guidelines existed. Thinking about it, if this student is eager to learn, he will try to understand what you've written, and if not, he probably won't be studying for too long ;-). So in any case, it's really not that much of a problem, I apologize :-).

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the String class lives in the **java.lang** package.

Comment: Yes, but there are other string manipulation classes that live in java.util, like StringTokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Java, but here is the worst case approach.

If you don't want to use split() method, then

```
  string text = "My name is Khan";

    int length = text.Length;

    int numberOfWords = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == ' ')
        {
            numberOfWords++;
        }
    }

    numberOfWords += 1; // no of words will be always plus one than no of space.

    string[] wordCollection = new string[numberOfWords];

    int wordLocation = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == ' ')
        {
            wordLocation++;
        }

        wordCollection[wordLocation] += text[i];
    }

    string reversedString = string.Empty;

    foreach (string str in wordCollection)
    {
        reversedString = str + " " + reversedString;
    }

    Console.Write(reversedString.Trim());
```

If this is homework and its transferred to some one, then you are the looser

Comment: Definitely not using any Java package ;-)